# Why is "the xxx authorities" in plural form?

Tags: grammatical-number

E.g. The American/Russian/Chinese authorities. I think the subject should be one unit, unless the country was split.

Or should I compare this expression to "the committee", to which some elements agree with in plural form, since "committee" has a plural meaning semantically?

Comment: "Authorities" refers to more than one person. If you were talking about a sports team, you'd say "the American players". I don't think it runs any deeper than that.

Comment: The singular defaults to an expert individual associated with that country. Compare: “The **US authority** claimed that the country had emerged from recession.” vs “The **US authorities** claimed that the country had emerged from recession.”

Comment: To rephrase existing comments, *the authorities* is a set phrase that will be in the plural even without any adjective at all.

Answer (score 3):

Authority is used in the plural form when you refer to organizations of a specific country:

***[the authorities:](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/the-authorities)***

> [plural] the people or organizations that are in charge of a particular country or area.
>
> - an agreement between the US and Colombian authorities

(Longman Dictionary)

Comment: I know it came from the dictionary, but that particular example is a little odd: the "the" makes it read as "[the US] and [Colombian authorities]", so that shows the plural form in reference to only one country's authorities, but it seems odd not to refer to both countries the same way, either "between US and Colombian authorities" or "between the US and Colombia".

Comment: @nnnnnn: they are referred to the same way. There's an implicit *the* in it: *"the US [authorities] and [the] Columbian authorities.* I'll agree it's easy to misinterpret, but I'm fairly sure that was the original intent.

Comment: @PeterShor - Sure, but really my point is that however you read it it's not a very good example for what the OP asked about, because when talking about two countries the *authorities* would need to be plural anyway.

Comment: Right. If you substituted "President", it would also be plural.